# any general formula for $a^{1/2} + a^{1/3} + a^{1/4} + a^{1/5} + \cdots+ a^{1/n}$ ??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I met a question like: (if $a$ is an integer)

any general formula for

$$a^{1/2} + a^{1/3} + a^{1/4} + a^{1/5} + \cdots+ a^{1/n}\text{ ??} $$

if a∈N,  how to prove

$$a^{1/2} + a^{1/3} + a^{1/4} + a^{1/5} + +\cdots+ a^{1/n} < a^{2/3}\text{ ??} $$

or how to prove

$$a^{1/2} + a^{1/3} + a^{1/4} + a^{1/5} + +\cdots+ a^{1/n} < a^{K/L}\text{ ??} $$

where K<L; a, K and L are all integers.

so what are K and L?

Thanks

Comment: The  inequality cannot be true. For large $n$, we have $a^{1/n} \approx 1$ and so the sum diverges.

Comment: What is $a$? Is $a$ negative and $n$ odd?

Comment: Note that $$
\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {a^{1/k} }  \ge \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n 1  = n - 1
$$ and $n - 1 < a^{2/3}$ will fail for $n$ large enough.

Comment: I forgot to add condition: Sorry ;
a is an integer, a>1; a is 2,3 4,5,6,.....

Comment: Do you mean to solve for $n$?  (Per lhf, it cannot hold for all $n$, so attempting to generalize it as you have done in your latest edit is futile)

Answer (score 4):

So, first note (as mentioned in multiple comments) that $a^{1/n}\rightarrow 1$ for large $n$; so the partial sums $a^{1/2}+a^{1/3}+\ldots+a^{1/n}$ are at the very least going to be asymptotic to $n$ for large $n$.  (That is, they certainly aren't bounded by any function of $a$.). But you can get a good characterization of the behavior from the following expansion:
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n}a^{1/k}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\log a)^i}{k^i i!}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(1+\frac{\log a}{k}+\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{(\log a)^i}{k^i i!}\right)\\ =(n-1)+\left(H_n - 1\right)\log a+\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{(\log a)^i}{i!}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k^i}.
$$
The first term is $\Theta(n)$; the second is $\Theta(\log a \cdot \log n)$; and the remaining terms converge to an analytic function of $\log a$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.  In particular, we have
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{(\log a)^i}{i!}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k^i} =\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(i)-1}{i!}(\log a)^i.
$$
The coefficients go to zero at least as fast as $1/(i!)$, so this is an entire function.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, Guru,

any idea for:
        a^(1/2)+a^(1/3)+a^(1/4)+a^(1/5)+⋯+a^(1/n) < a^(K/L) ??

Where, all a, K, L are integers and >1;

What are K, and L?

Please throw some lights.  
Thanks

Comment: Accept his answer, there is no way to someone make a better one.

Answer (score 0):

If $a>1$ is a real number, then $a^x = f(x)$ is increasing and

$$\begin{align} \sum^{n}_{i=2} a^{1/i} =  & a^{1/2} + a^{1/3} + a^{1/4} + a^{1/5} +\cdots + a^{1/n} \\ 
\leq & (n-1)a^{1/2} \\ 
= & (n - 1) \ln(e^{a^{1/2}}) \\
\leq & e^{a^{1/2} (n- 1)} - 1
\end{align}$$ That was the better I could do for now.

Comment: Great job. Appreciated
Thanks so much